# Divide content dynamically relative to 100%

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to divide my to content in to similar parts relative to 100%. For example: if "Overview" needs height of 60 than "Features" should automatically get height of 40.

[image]

Comment: How are your cells built in general? Are you using AutoLayout? Do you already have the code to calculate the height(s)? What happens if Overview requires 100%? What happens if Overview can't fit in 100%?

Comment: What are those yellow, grey, orange and red boxes supposed to be? Are they in any way related to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question lacks some data : 100% is a ratio, so it's 100% of 'what' length ?

I you take the superView's height as 100% reference, then it's quite easy, using autolayout (be sure to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO on your views) :

```
UIView * superView;//ou reference view whose height serves as 100%

float overViewHeightRatio = 0.6; // 60%

NSLayoutConstraint *overViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:overView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:overViewHeightRatio constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *featureHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:featureView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:(1 - overViewHeightRatio) constant:0];

// add other constraints : width, X and Y positioning for both overview & feature view
```

(**EDIT :** from Micantox comment)

Comment: The second constraint should be `constraintWithItem:featureView`, you should also mention that this solution will only work if the OP is using autolayout.